# How to build a jabber client using libstrophe

Tags: objective-c, c, osx-lion, xmpp, libstrophe

I'm trying to make a simple Jabber client using the [libstrophe](http://strophe.im/libstrophe/) library.

It's going fairly well so far, except for one thing for which I need some clarification.

Namely, how am I supposed to (continuously) know the status (i.e., Online/Offline) of contacts, so that I can display it to the user of my program? Similarly, how am I supposed to request the roster of the user?

I've looked at the `roster.c` example provided by libstrophe, but that only prints out the roster once. In a real application, I'll need to request/update this continuously, in order to show any new contacts the user added, etc., in the application.

So basically, I'm unclear on how to make sure that I always display the most current roster and most current statuses of people in my user's contact list.

Am I just supposed to request the roster at some predefined time interval, for example?

Comment: Looks like you're looking for "Roster Pushes": https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-xmpp-3921bis-06#section-2.1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

roster and presence are 2 different topics.

When you login you normally request the roster which you are doing already. When your contact lists changes during your session you get a **roster push** with the updated contact. This is an  stanza. It doesn't matter if another logged in client manipulated the roster our your client.

The online state called presence of all your subscribed contact comes in with  stanzas.

You have to setup handlers with **xmpp_handler_add** for

1. Online state, presence stanzas
2. Roster pushes, iq stanzas with query of namespace jabber:iq:roster

Comment: So to get roster pushes, I'd register a handler for `jabber:iq:roster`. What would be the namespace of the presence stanzas? Something like `jabber:iq:presence`?

Comment: presence is in the tag <presence/> and namespace jabber:client, roster pushes have the tag <iq/>, namespace is also jabber:client, and namespace of the payload (query tag) is jabber:iq:roster.

Comment: hmm I must be doing something wrong. I registered the handler for presence like this: `xmpp_handler_add(conn, presence_handler, "jabber:client", "presence", NULL, ctx);` but it never gets called... Not at start (so I get the initial presence information), not when somebody logs out when my program is running...

Comment: try this:
xmpp_handler_add(conn, presence_handler, NULL, "presence", NULL, ctx);
The namespace is not required for this handler.

Comment: that works, thanks. For the other handler I did `xmpp_handler_add(conn, roster_push_handler, "jabber:iq:roster", "iq", NULL, ctx);` and it seems to work too. Thanks for the answer, accept, +1, awarding bounty :)